# Google Maps API - Map no longer displays

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, driving-directions

I setup a directions page for a small company that I do work for. It
has a few markers and lets people get directions to the location from
wherever they are. For some reason, the page decided to stop coming up
in the browser. I've done just about anything I could think and
nothing has worked.  I'm not the best at javascript but I honestly
cannot figure what is incorrect. I did try to reissue the key thinking
that might be cause the issue but it did not work. Below I have
included the link to the page:

alfordmotorsonline.com/directions.html

Answer (score 2):

Your 'initialize()' function does not appear to be getting called.  Try adding something like:

```
window.onload = function () {
    initialize();
}
```

to your javascript and see if that helps.

Comment: Alternatively, Google's examples use this body tag:
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">

Comment: If you are using something like Go Live (which it looks like you are), going with Adam's onload may be better, since it will be less likely that GoLive will alter it (whereas it might re-write the body tag)